# USB Installed Ubuntu server fails to load without USB

Tags: boot, server, usb

I have tried installing the Ubuntu server (version 14.04) onto my acer desktop using my USB. I configured the USB through Universal USB Installer (version 1.9.5.7), using the option that said Ubuntu Server Installer.

I booted into the USB and did the installation, making sure to check that I installed it on the hard drive and not on the USB. After the installation finished, I removed the USB, as the prompt asked, and I restarted the computer. All I got after that was a black screen with a blinking underscore on the top left. I waited a while to see if it would change, but it did not. Then I booted in with the USB and the server worked. However, I do not need it on a USB; I need it on the computer's hard drive.

I did this process twice and got the same results.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, I made sure to have everything install outside of the USB. I think it may have to do with Universal USB Installer...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after some trial and error, I found out that Universal USB Installer does not properly install the Ubuntu Server, of all options. Therefore, I had to use Rufus to create my bootable USB. After that, everything went perfectly. If anyone has an idea of why this is the case, I would be very interested to know.

After all, I've used UUI for many other installs and it worked perfectly. Why wouldn't it work with the Ubuntu Server option?